# Model failing to save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I searched for a solution for the problem, but I cannot find the root cause of the issue.

I have a couple of models in my Rails application, two of which, `Category` and `Activity`, have a many-to-many relationship. In both the `Category` and `Activity` models, I defined this relationship using `has_and_belongs_to_many`. I created a joining table between the two. Please find my DB scheme here: https://pastebin.com/wc4TsPQQ.

The form to create a new Activity contains a field to select one or more categories to match:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {include_hidden: false}, {:multiple=>'true', :class=>'form-control'} %>
```

When I try to submit the form the `activities.category_id` field seems to not be "registred" (not sure about the right terminology). Rails either throws a

```
"category cannot be blank"
```

error or, when I temporary disable presence validation on Category, the error

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: activities.category_id
```

Looking in the request parameters however, the category ID is being sent by the form:

```
{"authenticity_token"=>"MD5eM5H7DG6RkjD+/QSZ5RqkAnJupJ3L/V044r+QP6s0651mv4hoTSSa8NXB3x959dpwKsSQhBTi58idDMm9hA==",
 "activity"=>{"name"=>"fsdffdf", "description"=>"sddfdsf", "location"=>"sdfsdf", "category_id"=>["3"], "user_id"=>"3"},
 "commit"=>"Save Activity"}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but I did notice that you have a category_id field on your activities table which isn't what you want if the relationship is many-to-many. You should probably remove that column.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't beg for help; We're here to help so begging merely muddies the question. Also, don't use salutations, valedictions or signatures like "Hi" or "Thanks a lot" or "Kevin". SO provides that information automatically. Think of SO as an online encyclopedia or reference book; https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior explains.

Comment: Please don't link to essential information, instead summarize the important part in the question itself. Links rot then break and when they do the information is lost making the question less useful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you seem to have created a `activities.category_id` column with a not-null constraint which is not needed here. You might want to re-read "[The `has_and_belongs_to_many` Association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)" documentation.

To get rid of the column you can either roll back and alter the migration that created the table in the first place or create a migration to remove the column:

```
class RemoveCategoryIdFromActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    remove_reference :activities, :category, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Also remove the `belongs_to :category` association in your `Activity` model which causes the "category cannot be blank" validation error.

Then you should be using `category_ids` and not the singular `_id`.

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name, {include_hidden: false}, {multiple: 'true', class: 'form-control' } %>
```

And make sure you correctly whitelist it:

```
params.require(:activity)
      .permit(:name, :description, :current_location, category_ids: [])
```

Comment: Also on a side note - do not pass the current user through the params if thats what `user_id` is. It makes it really trivial for a malicious user to just pass another users id with cURL or just the web inspector. Instead get the current user from the session in the controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this brought me one step further.

I whitelisted `category_ids` in the Activity controller as you suggested, but when I declare it as an array `category_ids[]`, upon saving rails throws the error `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)`

Params are then as follows, which then seem to be missing `category_ids` from my form:
`{"authenticity_token"=>"GipycRGVCkgVnAA0gt/To8hnnearoPJyywXrO+lfUq7d0tHMUqbBqZ0cNjYB3LBGbhIpA1QRu2ql8Ui4msnLkg==",
 "activity"=>{"name"=>"", "description"=>"", "location"=>"", "user_id"=>"3"},
 "commit"=>"Save Activity"}`

Comment: Fair remark on passing the `user_id`. It indeed wasn't my intention to keep this in the final Rails application,  but I yet have to build a mechanism to retrieve the `user_id` from the current user logged_in (via the Devise gem).

Comment: I have fixed a typo in my form. Now the `activity_ids` is passed, but rails still throws a `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)` error. 

Params are:
`{"authenticity_token"=>"UkB5+IppDWVBnZ+A6fHvdw4/lSbc5LGuckw869lbbHtWlbqtpBppRvSVX6vVKmnr4UHnfnbQqHFt9syUagLuVA==",
 "activity"=>{"name"=>"", "description"=>"", "location"=>"", "category_ids"=>["3", "4"], "user_id"=>"3"},
 "commit"=>"Save Activity"}`

Comment: `wrong number of arguments` is a really generic error and tells me absolutely nothing without a stack trace. It does not even have to be related to the issue you're originally asking about. I'm going to leave it up to figure this out.

Comment: I accidentally included `:category_ids []` instead of `category_ids: []` inside the controller, which caused the error. All is fine now. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1):

You want category "ids" not "id" since you have multiple ids to set.

Change to `f.collection_select :category_ids, .....`, make sure you are permitting an array for that attribute on your controller too.